# Subgroups - Klein bottle

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

Let $G$ be the fundamental group of the Klein bottle,

$G = \langle x,y \ ; \ yxy^{-1}=x^{-1} \rangle = {\mathbb Z} \rtimes {\mathbb Z} \ .$

What are the nilpotent subgroups of $G$?

I was only able to find a normal series of abelian subgroups with cyclic quotients in $G$, namely

$1\leq \langle y^2 \ ; \ \ \rangle\leq \langle x,y^2 \ ; \ xy^2=y^2x \rangle\leq G \ .$

Since I'm not an algebraist, I'm sorry if this a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: Does nilpotence of a subgroup correspond to something interesting in the covering space?

Comment: @da Fonseca: Every cyclic subgroup is abelian, hence nilpotent.

Comment: @Aaron: I don't know.

Comment: Is there a shorter (yet elementary) argument showing that $G$ is not nilpotent?

Comment: Shorter than what? The commutator $[x^a,y] = x^{-a}y^{-1}x^ay = x^{-2a}$, so $[x,y,{}_n x]\neq 1$ for all positive integers $n$ (where $[a,{}_1b] = [a,b]$ and $[a,{}_{n+1}b] = [a,{}_n b,b]$). So the group is not nilpotent.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear - sorry.  
I was wondering if we couldn't simply quote any of the basic results on (torsion-free f.g.) nilpotent groups to solve the problem (e.g., subnormality, non-trivial center, normalizer condition, poly-{\mathbb Z},...).  Clearly the infinite dihedral is a quotient of $G$, so $G$ is not nilpotent. If you don't know that the infinite dihedral is not nilpotent, some calculation is needed, of course.

Comment: There are no silly questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every cyclic subgroup is abelian, hence nilpotent. Every such subgroup is generated by an element of the form $x^ay^b$ with $a$ and $b$ integers.

In addition, $y^2$ commutes with $x$. Since $y^2$ is central, to determine the commutator of two elements we only need to consider the parity of the exponents of $y$ in their normal forms. Elements of the form $x^ay^{2b}$ and $x^ry^{2s}$ commute; elements of the form $x^ay^{2k+1}$ and $x^r$ commute if and only if $r=0$; and elements of the form $x^ay^{2k+1}$ and $x^ry^{2s+1}$ commute if and only if $a=r$. That gives you lots of abelian subgroups that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

What about higher nilpotency? Suppose you have two noncommuting elements in your subgroup. It is not hard to check that $[x^ay^{2b+1},x^r] = x^{2r}$ and  $[x^ay^{2b+1},x^r y^{2s+1}] = x^{2a-2r}$. But no nontrivial power of $x$ commutes with an element of the form $x^a y^{2b+1}$; and further commutators will just yield further nontrivial powers of $x$ that still do not commute with an element of the form $x^ay^{2b+1}$. So if your subgroup $H$ has an element of the form $h_1=x^a y^{2b+1}$, and $h$ is any nontrivial element of $H$ that is not a power of $h_1$, then $h_1$ and $h$ do not commute, and $h_1$ does not commute with any of $[h_1,h]$, $[h_1,h,h_1]$, $[h_1,h,h_1,h_1],\ldots,[h_1,h,h_1,\ldots,h_1]$, etc. But if $H$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then any commutator of weight $c$ would be central in $H$. Thus, $H$ cannot be nilpotent.

So the only  nilpotent subgroups of $H$ are abelian, and they are given as above.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a topological version of Arturo's argument.  (I'd leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep.)

Every covering space of the Klein bottle is a surface, and it's fairly easy to convince yourself that the infinite-degree ones have cyclic, hence nilpotent, fundamental group.

It remains to consider the finite-degree covering spaces.  Well, these are all closed surfaces of Euler characteristic zero (because Euler characteristic is <strike>nilpotent</strike> multiplicative), so by the classification of surfaces they are either tori or Klein bottles.  As already noted, the Klein-bottle group itself is not nilpotent, so only the abelian subgroups are left.

Comment: Very nice answer! Forgive me, but what do you mean by "Euler characteristic is nilpotent". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I meant 'multiplicative'.